# Google play services in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I created simple game and now I want add a leaderboards. i followed google documentation for it but every time when I want to get leaderboard i get this error:

```
W/GmsClient: IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must contain at least one of the Games scopes!
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1958)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.IGmsServiceBroker$Stub$zza.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.4.0:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.4.0:268)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zac.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.4.0:22)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zac.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.4.0:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacb.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.4.0:43)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacb.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.4.0:49)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.4.0:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I am logged in because with this i get my name

```
Log.d("name", String.valueOf(account.getGivenName()));
```

here is a code of getLeaderboard():

```
private void showLeaderboard() {
    String s = getString(R.string.leaderboard_id);
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);
                }
            });
}
```

in build.gradle i have:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:21.0.0"
```

project on google console I have created, leaderboard i have created and OAuth2.0 too SHA1  is set correctly

what can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Which scopes have you requested when signing the user in? You must use DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN like so

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build();
```